# Is it possible to change the "terminated" state of an EC2 instance in AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I terminated an instance because I had no more use for it, but to avoid creating another one I want to know if it is possible to reactivate it, I've tryed in the management console but reactivate doesn't look like an option ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, once an instance is terminated, it's gone.

That's why they have the termination protection bit you can enable for critical instances.